# Docker: ssh hangs after entering password

Tags: ssh, docker

My problem is almost exactly the same as the following [link](https://superuser.com/questions/659616/ssh-session-hangs-when-trying-to-open-a-shell), except my ssh server is in a docker container.

My Dockerfile is very simple.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server less nano
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN adduser chrome
RUN echo "chrome:chrome" | chpasswd
RUN echo "root:chrome" | chpasswd

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd",  "-D"]
```

When I try to ssh login, it hangs forever starting the shell.

```
$ ssh -p2222 chrome@localhost /bin/bash --noprofile --norc  # trying to login with ssh
chrome@localhost's password:    <-------------hangs forever
```

I can login if I use the `-t` argument on ssh. I don't know why.

Running other programs like `ls` works without problems. Perhaps someone can replicate this container and figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with docker, you can get the same thing to happen when you ssh to a remote host.

A clue to the problem is in the ssh man page

> -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi-
>                trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
>                very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
>                options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

So, ssh doesn't use a tty allocation if you provide a remote command to be run unless you use the `-t` switch. As bash is interactive it requires a tty.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I also have another physical ubuntu 12.04 server running sshd. I can login to that physical server without `-t`. So why do I need `shh -t` to login to the docker server?

Comment: Are you running the exact same command when you connect to the Ubuntu server, when I ran the same command to a CentOS server I experienced the same issue.

Comment: Both the physical and docker servers are running Ubuntu 12.04. A big difference is that the physical server also has a full desktop installed. The physical server does not require me to use the ssh `-t` flag. I'm trying figure out why the docker is requiring `-t`, and how to allow login without `-t`.

Comment: You haven't answered the question I asked.

Comment: My apologies. Logging into the physical server, I use `ssh -p $PORT user@$IP`. Logging into docker, I use `ssh -p $PORT user@$IP /bin/bash`. I see your point now. When I append `/bin/bash` to the end of my physical login, it also hangs.

Comment: Now I see I'm able to normally login now to the docker if I just don't specify `/bin/bash` at the end.

Comment: Technically, I don't think it's hanging. You're logged in and running `/bin/bash`. Bash isn't printing a command prompt because it doesn't think it's running interactively, and you think it's hung because you didn't get a command prompt. If you were to type a command (that didn't need a TTY), it would probably work.

Comment: @Kenster yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The following will not hang

```
$ ssh -p2222 chrome@localhost /bin/bash -i --noprofile --norc
```

The `-i` option for bash is required to get an *interactive* shell.

---

From the Bash Reference Manual [1.2 What is a shell?](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#What-is-a-shell_003f-1) section:

> Shells may be used interactively or non-interactively. In interactive mode, they accept input typed from the keyboard. When executing non-interactively, shells execute commands read from a file.

and [6.3.1 What is an Interactive Shell?](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f):

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments, unless -s is specified, without specifying the -c option, and whose input and error output are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.
>
> An interactive shell generally reads from and writes to a user’s terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue for a similar attempt to only ssh `ssh -p 2222 chrome@localhost` into my local container and this wasn't working with the same hanging terminal. All proposed solutions with `-t` or adding `/bin/bash --noprofile --norc` or `/bin/bash -i --noprofile --norc` didn't work until I switched to WSL terminal instead of cygwin. `ssh -p 2222 chrome@localhost` is working now and it looks like this was a cygwin issue. Maybe this can help somebody, too.

Answer (score -1):

When you start a container with `docker run` you have to specify `-it` for an interactive terminal for the exact same reason as explained above.

As an observation from your `dockerfile` you can add `--net=host` to your `docker run` command so that the container can access the native NIC configurations if you do not want to use `EXPOSE 22` explicitly.

Also, (as dumb as it sounds, I know) I have had issues at login with docker even on a local container where it ***appears*** to hang but if I just hit `<enter>` I then get the prompt...

Comment: This has nothing to do with docker; it's a function of running ssh with a command argument.

Comment: @JennyD I do understand that and the prior answers do explain that point well, I was simply trying to add ```docker``` specific input and reminding the OP that it was also necessary to interact with the shell in ```docker``` itself ....for the same reason. I have edited my prior answer to be more clear. I do not see a reason to downvote...